# How to test that a method is called by Guava Cache only once

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, guava

I'm trying to test that a cache I created is working properly, and duplicate calls to a method aren't actually called multiple times, but loaded from my cache.

I'm using LoadingCache from Google Guava to accomplish this.

So my naive approach was to create a spy, and verify that the method was called once. I then figured out that because spy() is a decorator, I can only see if the method was called on that object. Since the method is being called by LoadingCache, my spy cannot verify it.

How do I best test that my cache is being used properly?

(note: I could make a LoadingCache dependency, and check that the correct method is called, but then I don't know if my cache is working. Maybe the hash is calculated in a way I didn't anticipate, and so it actually is calling the method every time. I want to actually see the effect)

```java
private final LoadingCache<TaskDetails, byte[]> cache;

    ...

    cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(cacheSize)
                .expireAfterAccess(Duration.ofMinutes(cacheDurationInMinutes))
                .build(CacheLoader.from(this::doTask));
```

```java
public byte[] taskCaller(...) {
    ...
    return cache.getUnchecked();
}
```

```java
public byte[] doTask(...) {
    if(something.doSomething() ... ) {
    ...
}
```

First test attempt doesn't work, Mockito says: Wanted but not invoked (the method was "never called", since the spy doesn't know the cache called it)

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    // given
    TaskService spy = spy(
        new TaskService(...)
    );

    // when
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        spy.taskCaller(...);
    }

    // then
    //if caching is working, we should only do the real work once
    verify(spy, times(1)).doTask(any(TaskDetails.class));
}
```

Second attempt: NullPointerException on first statement in the method ( something.doSomething() ), I'm not completely sure why, but I'm convinced for the same reason as before

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    // given
    TaskService spy = spy(
        new TaskService(...)
    );
    final int[] counter = {0};
    when(spy.doTask(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        counter[0]++;
        return new byte[]{0,0,0,0};
    });

    // when
    int run = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < run; i++) {
        spy.taskCaller(...);
    }

    // then
    //if caching is working, we should only do the real work once
    assertThat(run).isEqualTo(counter[0]);
    verify(spy, times(1)).doTask(any(TaskDetails.class));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. [Enable cache stats recording](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#recordStats()), interact with the cache, [get the cache stats](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#stats--), then verify that the [load count](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheStats.html#loadCount--) (and possibly other stats) are what you expect.
2. Make your `CacheLoader` a separate named class rather than a method reference, an instance of which is passed to `CacheBuilder.build()`, and arrange for that instance to be a mock in your test. You can then verify method call counts and arguments on your mock loader.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm using LoadingCache from Google Guava to accomplish this.

That's the point. If you trust Guava enough, why don't you trust that its tests work?

Did you write the cache? No, you didn't. Then don't test it as part of unit tests: only as part of integration tests, with the rest of the whole application.

Just test that the cache-loading method is called when you invoke your cache-using method.

If you want to test that you have a cache, perform two calls on the general method, and verify that the cache-loading method is called only once.